# Keyboard mnemonics not working

Tags: c, gtk

In the below code, I expect <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> to hide/show the child of the `GtkExpander` but it is not happening.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{

    GtkWidget *window, *expander, *label;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Expander");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 200, 100);

    expander = gtk_expander_new_with_mnemonic ("Click Me _For More!");
    label = gtk_label_new ("Hide me or show me,\nthat is your choice.");
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (expander), label);

    gtk_expander_set_expanded (GTK_EXPANDER (expander), TRUE);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), expander);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which platform? Are you sure Ctrl is the modifier used?

Comment: @unwind: I am on Linux Ubuntu 64Bit OS.

Comment: @unwind : I double checked the modifier, It is Alt and not Ctrl. Thankyou for  that suggestion. Smashed it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per unwind's suggestion, I double checked the default modifier
and it is <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>. The problem is solved.